# Maquina de estados com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou com problemas pra implementar uma maquina de estados usando AngularJS..

Nas minhas primeira tentativa, tentei utilizar essa feita em JS: https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine

Não consegui fazer ele funcionar como eu desejava.. Segui os exemplos e não obtive resultado. O que tentei foi criar alguns passos simples utilizando somente **console.log()** pra ver por onde ela passava, e acabei por notar que não passa por todos os estados que eu defini, ela simplesmente executa o primeiro estado:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ConfigurationCtrl', function($scope, $http){

$scope.welcome = "Welcome to the jungle"
$scope.percentBar = 0;

var fsm = StateMachine.create({

  events: [
    { name: 'play', from: 'none', to: 'game' },
    { name: 'quit', from: 'game', to: 'teste' },
    { name: 'stop', from: 'teste', to: 'game' }
  ],

  callbacks: {

    onentermenu: function() { console.log("onentermenu"); },
    onentergame: function() { console.log("onentergame"); },
    onenterteste: function() {console.log("onenterteste")},

    onleavemenu: function() {
        trace("onleavemenu");
      $http.get("http://192.168.11.51:8080/sigetall").sucess(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        fsm.transition();   
      });         
      return StateMachine.ASYNC; 
    },

    onleavegame: function() {
        console.log("fuck")
      $http.get("http://192.168.11.51:8080/sigetall").sucess(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        fsm.transition();   
      });         
      return StateMachine.ASYNC; 
    },

    onleaveteste: function() {

    }

  }
});

console.log(fsm.current)
fsm.play();
console.log(fsm.current)
});
```

resultado:

```
none
ConfigurationCtrl.js:17 onentergame
ConfigurationCtrl.js:47 game
```

Acabei alterando o método onentermenu e deixando ele igual ao onleavemenu para ver como ele trabalharia assync e ele retorna erro dizendo que o método **fms.transition()** não existe.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Troque:

```js
fsm.transition();
```

Por:

```js
this.transition();
```